# How do I add a value to my txt file one time only?

Tags: c#

I have this code, which adds a line into my Students.txt, however, everytime I compile and run the code, it does it again. What code can I add so that the new record is only added once?

```
string newLastName = "'Constant";
string newRecord = "(LIST (LIST 'Constant 'Malachi 'D ) '1234567890 'mdconstant@mail.usi.edu 4.000000 )";
string line;
string lastName;
bool insertionPointFound = false;

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count && !insertionPointFound; i++)
{
    line = lines[i];
    if (line.StartsWith("(LIST (LIST "))
    {
        values = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
        lastName = values[2];
        if (newLastName.CompareTo(lastName) < 0)
        {
            lines.Insert(i, newRecord);
            insertionPointFound = true;
        }
    }
}

if (!insertionPointFound)
{
    lines.Add(newRecord);                          //This record is always added, making the file longer over time 
                                                    //if it is not deleted each time from the Students.txt file in 
}                                                  //the bin folder.

File.WriteAllLines("Students.txt", lines);
```

Comment: With each run you want to write it all over again or want to append it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are writing is known or only to occur in the file once, then first open the file and check if the record-to-be-written exists in the file.  If it doesn't, then proceed to write it, otherwise don't write it.

```
if (!File.ReadAllText("students.txt").Contains(newRecord))
{
  // write to file...
}
```

Comment: Wow, this was an easy fix. Thanks so much! Works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if the file already is there(like in the code sample) or if it is already the way you want it, and just put it into an if statement

```
       if (File.Exists("Students.txt") == false)
        {
            File.WriteAllLines("Students.txt", lines);
        }
```

Although, this does beg the question, why are you generating all of the lines to write to the file in the first place every time?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in wrong `newLastName.CompareTo(lastName)` using.
If *newLastName* is equal to *lastName* than [*CompareTo*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx) returns 0.
And in this case you should set `insertionPointFound = true;`

```
if (newLastName.CompareTo(lastName) == 0)
{
    lines.Insert(i, newRecord);
    insertionPointFound = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to `delete` the file before entering into the method, since you are already overwriting again in your code -

```
if(File.Exists("Students.txt"))
{
   File.Delete("Students.txt");
}
```